# SAS: proc http working - request.get in Python does not - why?

Tags: python, http, sas, proc

have tried looking into other similar question and search the web, but I cannot seem to find the answer, so hope some clever people here can help or guide me.

I have a proc http request in SAS which runs fine on my local machine, no problems:

```
filename lst temp;
proc http
url = "http://xxx/api/job/"
method = "get"
out = lst;
run;
libname lst json fileref=lst automap=create;
```

Trying to do the same in Python gives me error code 401.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://xxx/api/job/")
print(response)
print(response.status_code)
```

This is an API from a system running internally in our organization. One needs to log on the first time when accessing through a web browser, but then it works.
I have tried all the different auth= etc. I could find in the documentation giving my user and password. But, nothing seems to work.

Some how, SAS proc http must be working since my profile/user is somehow verified, but via Python it is not - or at least that is what I am thinking.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Open your web browser, launch the developper tools (F12), go to the network tab.
Log into the site and check the parameters sent to and get from the API.
Then you can use requests.post('http://xxxx/api/job', data) where data contains all you need to log in.

Comment: use all the `Proc HTTP` features, such as, option `HEADER_OUT=` and statement  `DEBUG` statement, to get more info what what is being passed to server.

Comment: How is SAS running?  Are you using local SAS, or is this a server via Studio/EG, while python is local?  If it is not local SAS, then there's a chance your issue is related to authentication and/or firewalls.